# Replace nan values with data from previous months

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, nan

I have a DataFrame as follows. This DataFrame contains NAN values. I want to replace nan values with the earlier non nan value in my DataFrame from previous month(s):

```
date (y-d-m)  | value 
 2022-01-01   | 1  
 2022-02-01   | 2 
 2022-03-01   | 3     
 2022-04-01   | 4  
 ...
 2022-01-02   | nan  
 2022-02-02   | nan
 2022-03-02   | nan
 2022-04-02   | nan
 ... 
 2022-01-03   | nan  
 2022-02-03   | nan
 2022-03-03   | nan
 2022-04-03   | nan
```

Desired outcome

```
date (y-d-m)  | value 
 2022-01-01   | 1  
 2022-02-01   | 2 
 2022-03-01   | 3     
 2022-04-01   | 4  
 ...
 2022-01-02   | 1  
 2022-02-02   | 2
 2022-03-02   | 3
 2022-04-02   | 4
 ... 
 2022-01-03   | 1  
 2022-02-03   | 2
 2022-03-03   | 3
 2022-04-03   | 4
```

Data:

```
{'date (y-d-m)': ['2022-01-01', '2022-02-01', '2022-03-01', '2022-04-01',
                  '2022-01-02', '2022-02-02', '2022-03-02', '2022-04-02',
                  '2022-01-03', '2022-02-03', '2022-03-03', '2022-04-03'],
 'value': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert `"date (y-d-m)"` column to datetime; then `groupby` "day" and forward fill with `ffill` (values from previous months' same day):

```
df['date (y-d-m)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date (y-d-m)'], format='%Y-%d-%m')
df['value'] = df.groupby(df['date (y-d-m)'].dt.day)['value'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
   date (y-d-m)  value
0    2022-01-01    1.0
1    2022-01-02    2.0
2    2022-01-03    3.0
3    2022-01-04    4.0
4    2022-02-01    1.0
5    2022-02-02    2.0
6    2022-02-03    3.0
7    2022-02-04    4.0
8    2022-03-01    1.0
9    2022-03-02    2.0
10   2022-03-03    3.0
11   2022-03-04    4.0
```